# Combine each key and value of array with another array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have this two arrays:

```
$arr1 = Array ( 600 => 580, 500 => 480, 100 => 80 ) <- always 3

$arr2 = Array ( 'filt' => grey, 'or' => 90 ) <- this array is dynamic
```

How can I combine each key and value from first array with the other array? I mean, I need:

```
$array = ( 600 => 580, 'filt' => grey, 'or' => 90 )
$array = ( 580 => 480, 'filt' => grey, 'or' => 90 )
```

successively in for/foreach loop. How can I do this?
Thanks a lot, im new on php ^^ and sorry for my english :P

Comment: so you need three new arrays, each having an element for first array and rest is from second one? and what should be the output? array of arrays or three new different variables? be more specific.

Comment: @mitkosoft first of all, thanks for the reply. Okey, I need to do this: foreach of $arr1 (always 3) to make 3 urls, each one have to be: first key and value of the first array with the rest of the second one. To be more specific, for example: first url will be -> ?600=580&filt=grey&or=90. Next one: ?500=480&filt=grey&or=90... (the constructor i have already done). So i suppose that i dont need to make an array of arrays in the foreach, right? Thanks

Comment: @Jmack, Did you want only one array with `$array1` where the key, value pair added to the second `$array`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this. Just loop through the first array, copy the first array in the out array and add key, value of loop array into the out array.

> As you mention:
>
> ```
> $array = ( 600 => 580, 'filt' => grey, 'or' => 90 )
> $array = ( 580 => 480, 'filt' => grey, 'or' => 90 )
> ```
>
> I think you need to create different array each time. For each of the
>   element of first array you need different array as output.

```
$arr1 = array( "600" => 580, "500" => 480, "100" => 80 );
$arr2 = array( 'filt' => "grey", 'or' => 90 );

$out = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $out = $arr2;
    $out[$key] = $value;

    print_r($out);
}
```

**Result**

First Iteration:

```
Array
(
    [filt] => grey
    [or] => 90
    [600] => 580
)
```

Second Iteration:

```
Array
(
    [filt] => grey
    [or] => 90
    [500] => 480
)
```

Third Iteration:

```
Array
(
    [filt] => grey
    [or] => 90
    [100] => 80
)
```

Comment: Yeah! That's what I need! Thanks :) and thanks too for trying to understand me despite of my bad english exprtession.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = array( '600' => '580', '500' => '480', '100' => '80' ) ;
$arr2 = array( 'filt' => 'grey', 'or' => '90' );
$arra_new = array();
foreach($arr1 as $key=>$arr) {
  $temp = $arr2;
  $temp[$key] = $arr;
  $arra_new[] = $temp;
}
print '<pre>';print_r($arra_new);exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_walk` and `array_replace` functions:

```
$arr1 = Array(600 => 580, 500 => 480, 100 => 80);
$arr2 = Array('filt' => 'grey', 'or' => 90, 'and' => 150, 'if' => 10);
$combined = [];

array_walk($arr1, function($v, $k) use($arr2, &$combined) {
    $combined[] = array_replace([$k => $v], $arr2);
});

print_r($combined);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [600] => 580
            [filt] => grey
            [or] => 90
            [and] => 150
            [if] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [500] => 480
            [filt] => grey
            [or] => 90
            [and] => 150
            [if] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [100] => 80
            [filt] => grey
            [or] => 90
            [and] => 150
            [if] => 10
        )
)
```

Comment: This is what I need but the other user gives me another simpler answer, but this would also serve me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this method..

```
<?php 
$arr1 = array(600 => 580, 500 => 480, 100 => 80 );
$arr2 = array( 'filt' => 'grey', 'or' => 90 );

$newArray =array();
foreach($arr1 as $key =>$val)
{
    $temp =array();
    $temp[$key]= $val;
    $newArray[] =$temp+$arr2;
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($newArray);
?>
```

This will Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [600] => 580
            [filt] => grey
            [or] => 90
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [500] => 480
            [filt] => grey
            [or] => 90
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [100] => 80
            [filt] => grey
            [or] => 90
        )

)
```

Comment: @FrayneKonok, I've checked the OP's output and forgot to verify my output keys `600 500 100` are missed in... now edited the answer.
Thank you for pointing..

Comment: Yes i saw and remove the first comment.